# Naming Laravel Controllers for displaying products filtered by categories

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, naming

So my products (books) are filtered into Fiction / Non Fiction, and into subcategories for each, i've made all the logic for filtering and displaying the products but what i'm struggling with is naming the routes and controllers for it.

I thought of using one resource BookController with the standard 7 methods, and somehow passing a criterium, fiction/nonfiction or specific subcategory id into the index method, that then calls my BookService class which returns the proper collection.

I don't think posting my code will be very helpfull but just in case, these are my BookService methods

```
  /*
   Returns a collection of n random recommended books
   n = $quantity
  */
  public function getRecommended(int $quantity){
    return Book::with('authors')->get()->random($quantity);
  }

  /*
   Returns a collection of books by passed categoryId
  */
  public function getByCategory(int $categoryId){
    return Book::with('authors', 'category')->category($categoryId)->get();
  }

  /*
   Returns a collection of fiction books
  */
  public function getFiction(){
    return Book::with('authors', 'category')->nonFiction()->get();
  }

  /*
   Returns a collection of non fiction books 
  */
  public function getNonFiction(){
    return Book::with('authors', 'category')->fiction()->get();
  }
```

`fiction()`, `nonfiction()`, `category($categoryId)` are local scopes in my Book Eloquent Model.

**My question is**

1. What should I name controllers for displaying All books and Filtered books, and what should i call their methods?
2. Should i maybe use one BookController resource controller and somehow pass it's index method the criterium for filtering, if that's the proper way, can somebody help me with how to actually pass the criterum from my view with Blade Templates and how to set it up using `Route::resource(..)`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My opinion (and this is an opinionated question, so not a great fit for Stackoverflow) is a single `BookController`, as either a resource controller (index, show, new, edit, etc.) with custom methods (or a single, reusable method to handle a bunch of cases) or a custom controller. All of these methods seem appropriate for an `index` method, with additional params for type (fiction, nonfiction) or category, which could be from URL or Query params: `books/fiction`, or `books?type=fiction`, etc.

Comment: Also, there's an `inRandomOrder()` method you can use to avoid having to load every book into memory before calling `->random($quantity)`; see if `Book::with('authors')->inRandomOrder()->take($quantity)->get()` is more efficient than `Book::with('authors')->get()->random($quantity);` 

Comment: I guess you're right about the question being opinionated, should i delete it?

I wanted to do inRandomOrder() not sure why i went for ->random instead.. Thanks for pointing that out, I changed it to the code you provided.

Comment: You don't have to delete it, there's nothing wrong with it per-se, but it might get closed due to being the wrong type of question for Stackoverflow; up to you  We can still provide our opinions in the comments and what not, but you might not get the traction you're looking for. And  for the `inRandomOrder()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the laravel generated resources for controllers represents the **CRUD functions** (*create, read, update, delete*)  if you treat your eloquent models in your application as a **resource**.

i'm assuming that your problems are more about diplaying the books for your clients (visitors) a **READ** action.

Laravel doesn't force you to user the [default generated crud actions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller), if you need to create a method that is not in context of model only, for exemple getting the mode data for your book by calling an external ISBN api, it's totally olowed.

So i recommend keeping all your actions in "BookController"

- if you want to keep the default actions you can do your filtering inside the "**index**" method.
- if you want to add a "filter" method and add it in your routes, nothing in laravel is preventring you.

**NOTE :** for the "**getRecommended**" method, it's not optimized, you can use `Book::with("authrs")->inRandomOrder()->take($quantity)->get();`

Comment: I ended up using a modified index method in a resource controller, like having all controlellers 'cruddy'. 
Also fixed getRecommended per Tim Lewis's advice from comments, but thanks for pointing it out and replying
I'll accept this as answer.